# Animation snapping on loop when in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I have an animation that works fine on blender but whenever i import it into Unity there is a weird snapping when the animation loops.

This is how it looks on Blender: [BlenderAnim](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1roJ3DZEipx_2lMMmvyG548a_mlDrOZnv/view?usp=sharing)

This is how it looks on unity:[UniyAnim](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ci9WPNunIL2BDbnc51oenKHHqz_ChonN/view?usp=sharing)

I have tried remaking the animation, opening it on a different unity project, even remaking the entire model. nothing seems to work. other animations on different models seem to work fine.
I am exporting it as an fbx file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the clip is cut from the end. Try adjusting the frames included in clip right in clip properties [image: unity docs]

Also enabling "loop pose" may help

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. i think it helped a little bit, but there is still some snapping at the end of the loop. For some reason it looks like the animation is set up to start at frame 3 and i can't change that to 0. i can only make it start at later frames